# Delete the certain row of list which have the repeated content to the others

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to delete the row of list due to the certain idendical keyword inside.

This is for RF test report form to rearrange.
In the past, I've tried on deleting the row by picking up the list index,
however, it seems not a clever way.

```
list_1 = [['', '', 'Channel', 'Freq. (MHz)', 'Link Speed', 'Test Item', 'Lower Limit', 'Upper Limit', 'Measured', 'Unit', 'Status']
          ['', '', '1', '2442', 'MCS6', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.09', 'dBm', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2442', 'MCS6', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.56', 'dB', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2442', 'MCS6', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.45', 'dB', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2442', 'MCS6', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.38', 'dB', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2442', 'MCS6', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '663.96', 'Hz', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.29', 'dBm', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.16', 'dB', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.15', 'dB', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.18', 'dB', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '663.16', 'Hz', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.09', 'dBm', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.56', 'dB', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.45', 'dB', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.38', 'dB', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '663.96', 'Hz', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.02', 'dBm', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-32.08', 'dB', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.98', 'dB', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.56', 'dB', 'PASS']
          ['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '763.52', 'Hz', 'PASS']]
burstpower_i = [i for i,row in enumerate(list_1) if 'Burst Power (Average)' in row]
burstpower_iend = burstpower_i[-1] #Keep the last result to cover the previous ones
reindex = []
gap = burstpower_i[1] - burstpower_i[0]
for i,v in enumerate(burstpower_i):
        if (list_1[-1][3] == list_1[v][3]) and (list_1[-1][4] == list_1[v][4]):
            continue
        reindex.append(v)
for i in reindex:
        list_s = list_1[i:i+gap]
    list_end = list_1[burstpower_iend-gap:burstpower_iend]
    list_s.extend(list_end)
```

I expect the output that the last result of MCS7 can cover the previous ones.

```
['', '', 'Channel', 'Freq. (MHz)', 'Link Speed', 'Test Item', 'Lower Limit', 'Upper Limit', 'Measured', 'Unit', 'Status']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.09', 'dBm', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.56', 'dB', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.45', 'dB', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.38', 'dB', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS6', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '663.96', 'Hz', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'Burst Power (Average)', '-100', '30', '12.02', 'dBm', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM All Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-32.08', 'dB', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM Data Carriers (Average)', '', '-27', '-31.98', 'dB', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'EVM Pilot Carriers (Average)', '', '-8', '-33.56', 'dB', 'PASS']
['', '', '1', '2412', 'MCS7', 'Center Freq. Error (Average)', '-60300', '60300', '763.52', 'Hz', 'PASS']
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting all your data lists into a set ensures duplicates are eliminated.

```
s = set()
s.add(tuple(["", "123", "1234"]))
s.add(tuple(["", "123", "1234"]))
s.add(tuple(["", "abc", "abcd"]))
```

and so on. In the end, everything in the set would be unique.

```
list(s) == [("", "123", "1234"), ("", "abc", "abcd")] # a list of tuples
map(list, list(s)) == [["", "123", "1234"], ["", "abc", "abcd"]] # converted to a list of lists
```

NB. The reason you need to put tuples into the set instead of list is because tuples are hashable. The set object leverages that property to discover duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

A nice piece of software that allows to work efficiently with complicated data is [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Check it out:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(list_1)
data = data.drop_duplicates([4, 5])
new_list = data.values.tolist()
```